# C start a process without seeing the input or output

Tags: c, linux, systemd, init

I'm trying to write an init system, and I want to spawn a process without the IO. meaning, I don't want to see output or for it to take input. I currently use the function from suckless's sinit -

```
void spawn(char *const argv[]) {
    switch (fork()) {
        case 0:
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
            setsid();
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
            perror("execvp");
            _exit(1);
            break;
        case -1:
            perror("fork");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

but if I start a process (used `top` as a test), it doesn't run "in the background". how can I do that?

Comment: Use `daemon()` or double `fork()`?

Comment: @AllanWind double fork?

Answer (score 2):

All processes expect to inherit file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 from their parent process, as standard input, output and error, respectively.

The traditional approach involves redirecting them to `/dev/null`. All output disappears, and any attempts to read from standard input result in an immediately end-of-file indication.

And redirecting them to `/dev/null` consists of closing them, and opening `/dev/null` in their place.

```
void spawn(char *const argv[]) {
    switch (fork()) {
        case 0:
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
            setsid();
            close(0);
            close(1);
            close(2);
            open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
            open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
            open("/dev/null", O_wRONLY);
            execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

Robustness suggests meticulously checking if each `open()` succeeded, or not. But, if opening `/dev/null` fails you'll have more problems to worry about.

Comment: ok so I did this, and it seems to work, so thanks. but that is except for the fact that running `ps` doesn't show me the process. I tried starting `top` as the process, since it runs indefinitly pretty much, but it doesn't appear in ps. any ideas?

Comment: `ps` will show every running process, but not by default, see its manual page. If a process is running, `ps` will show it, if the right options are specified.

Comment: I tried `ps -aux`, didnt work. tried to tun `less` and check for it in `top`, but it's not there

Comment: `ps` has other options. Like `-e`. This is, in fact, mentioned as the very first example in the ps manual page: `ps -ef`. The process is either there and `ps` will show it, or `execv` has failed, or the process terminated before you ran `ps`. There are no other possibilities. You can save the returned pid from `fork()`, then grep the output of `ps` for that, specific process id.